# install xcode 5 side by side with xcode 4.x

Tags: xcode, compatibility

Is it possible to install **xcode 5** (release version NOT the developer preview) side by side with xcode 4.x? There seem to be compatibility issues with xib files created/edited with xcode 5 that won't open with older versions of xcode

Comment: Rename your current version XCode.app to something like XCode4.app, then download XCode5 dmg from iOS Dev Center and extract to Applications directory. I'm using both versions without a problem. Just as you said, do not open nib files with XCode5.

Comment: You can have two or more XCodes with different names in Applications folder.

Comment: @Puneet: you too.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to install xcode 5 (release version NOT the developer
>   preview) side by side with xcode 4.x?

**Sure**. Here are three ways you can do it.

1.If you're registered as an Apple Developer, you can download [previous versions of Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?q=xcode). Double click the downloaded **XCode.dmg** file. It would open the Xcode. Then go to `File Menu --> Open --> Choose Your Project --> Click Open`.

2.As @EPyLEpSY's comment, Rename your current version **XCode.app** to something like **XCode4.app**, then download **XCode5 dmg** from iOS Dev Center and extract to Applications directory.

3.When you are dragging xcode to applications folder after the downloaded .dmg extraction, choose "Keep Both" option from the Copy warning box.

> There seem to be compatibility issues with xib files created/edited
>   with xcode 5 that won't open with older versions of xcode

You can configure your xib files compatibility details in **Interface Builder Document** section to get rid of these issues.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** This will enable editing in Xcode earlier versions, but you will be unable to edit using the iOS 7 appearance.

Answer (score 3):

Drag your XCODE to `/Applications` folder, pick **Keep Both** on the prompt that showing up, so there will be 2 installed XCODE, your old one (XCODE 4) and the new one (XCODE 5)

[image]